# How to properly dismiss a UIAlertView programmatically in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uialertview

When my app enters the background, my modally presented view controller dismisses an alert view like so...

```
// called when view controller receives a UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.alertView) {
        [self.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
        self.alertView = nil;
    }
}
```

When my app returns to the foreground without having been terminated, the alert view is gone. However, the bar button items in the navigation bar (from a UINavigationController) are still dimmed as if the alert view were still displayed.

Moreover, dismissing the modal view controller (by tapping a dimmed bar button item) reveals that the bar button items for the presenting view controller are also dimmed. The bar buttons items are functional, but they remain dimmed.

So how do I un-dim the bar button items? Or, how do I properly dismiss an alert view programmatically in iOS 7 in response to the app entering the background?

The *iOS 7 UI Transition Guide* states the following:

> When an alert or action sheet appears, iOS 7 automatically dims the tint color of the views behind it. To respond to this color change, a custom view subclass that uses tintColor in its rendering should override tintColorDidChange to refresh the rendering when appropriate.

My navigation bars and bar button items are not custom views; I did not subclass them. I created the navigation bars in storyboard with their default attributes (same with the bar button items). So there's no place for me to override tintColorDidChange.

All of my views use the default value for their tintColor property.

I have tried re-seting the tint color to the default value without success:

```
if (self.alertView) {
        [self.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
        self.view.tintColor = nil;
        self.view.window.tintColor = nil;
        self.alertView = nil;
    }
```

I have also tried re-seting the tint color in the view controller's viewDidAppear: without success.

I also tried setting the main view's tintAdjustmentMode to "normal" without success:

```
if (self.alertView) {
    [self.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    self.alertView = nil;

    self.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
}
```

By the way, if the the app was terminated while in the background, the app relaunches with the bar button items having the correct tint (i.e., un-dimmed).

Comment: My alert views have been coming through the transition from background, much to my dismay.  I will look at this more, too.

Comment: Using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`, check what the currently active window is. Since UIAlertView has its own window, it may be that that window does not get dismissed properly, leaving your bar (button items) dimmed. You can also try dismissing it before the app becomes active again (`application:willEnterForeground:`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug on Apple's end. I've filed a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com, please file a duplicate bug report to get Apple to pay attention to it, as [that is how Apple assigns priority to bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports).

Comment: This seems more accurate. If the OS dismisses modals on background, then it should do it completely. In the mean time, you can use the standard `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` to dismiss it before your app is sent to the background

Comment: Any progress on this thing ?

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same bug in my app and successfully found a workaround. All you need to do is set tintAdjustmentMode to UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal on your application's main window after the UIAlertView is dismissed in background. Easy :)

Comment: You're saying do `self.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;` right? I tried that and it didn't work for me, are you doing it in `applicationDidEnterBackground` (thats what i tried), or maybe are you doing it when you re-enter the foreground?

Comment: @MohamedHafez I call it next line after -[UIAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:]

Answer (score 5):

Although I can dismiss an alert view programmatically in response to a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, the automatic tint-dimming in iOS 7 will not get updated.

However, the automatic tint-dimming behavior will respond if I dismiss the alert view in response to a `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` instead.

```
// called when view controller receives a UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
- (void)applicationWillResignActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.alertView) {
        [self.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
        self.alertView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should still file a bug like @Mohamed says below.

Comment: Remember that opening the control center and notification center causes your app to resign active, and will cause the alert to be dismissed. This is not an optimal behavior. Consider using sgosha's solution.

Comment: @LeoNatan Please explain. On iOS 7, I am unable to swipe from the edge to display the control center or notification center while an alert is on-screen.

Comment: Hm this is a good point, but you can still get the OS alerts, which also make your app inactive.